# Is there any indication in Sons Of Anarchy that it does not take place in the present day?

Tags: sons-of-anarchy

I'm just curious, because **all** the technology you see in that show seems older.  The computers are always clunky desktops with floppy drives, and every cell phone is a flip-phone.  You'd think at least **one** person in Charming owns a smartphone!  Or a laptop.  Or at least a tower.  The cars seem a little older, too.  Not sure about the bikes, I'm not a rider so I wouldn't know and that might be fudged because Harley Davidson is sponsoring the show and they probably threw a few newer models into the mix as product placement. So is there any indication that Sons Of Anarchy does not take place in the present day?

Comment: Interesting theory, but Tara [drives a 2012 Ford](http://sonsofanarchy.wikia.com/wiki/Tara_Knowles) and I think she uses a smartphone.

Comment: I would turn your question around, in that you've given us indications that it might be taking place in the near past. Asking what indications there are that it is actually taking place in the present is a more natural evolution of your thesis.

Comment: Wouldn't that be nuts if it all turned out to be a prequel to Abel's story, since he seems to be getting more agressive?

Comment: simplest answer: no

Comment: The reason they use the old flip phone is because they buy the pre-paid cheap phones because they throw them away after a short period of time, they don't keep them around for security purposes. There are new cars in there. Even though the computers are old, there is evidence that suggests the show occurs in current time. Keep in mind, Charming isn't a tech mecha and a lot of sleepy towns are out-dated.

Comment: I could see Abel now... man, those old hogs, sheesh pops, get modern... as he zips away on his Nuda 900R

Comment: Wait, flip phones are old technology? I still remember rotary dials on land-line phones! What's old? 2013?

Comment: The producers of shows like this think it's more dramatic to watch a man open a phone to answer it and shut it closed to end the call...looks better than pulling out a smart phone and sliding a finger across the screen....other shows do it as well.

Comment: When they are in Belfast you would think it was the 70's

Answer (score 8):

There are plenty of recent vehicles (Tara's, Gemma's, Pope's, etc). As for phones, I'm pretty sure that both Tara and their lawyer have been shown using smartphones. The club members are shown with flip-phones because often the cheap, no-contract style phones (at least here in the US) are the older style flip phones. It's much easier to use those as "burner" phones. The only computer I remember off hand is in the office at Teller-Morrow and I don't think it's unusual to see that. I've been to quite a few auto repair places that still have old clunky computers with CRT monitors.

Comment: The episode before this one, Gemma and the junkie (I can never remember Drea's character's name!) are talking about whether Juice told Jacks anything.  I'm pretty sure they're at Jacks' house.  In that scene, there's another old, clunky desktop with a floppy drive in it.

Comment: In a business like theirs, do you think they're going to keep the data in the cloud? Heck no, probably a few spreadsheets saved to floppy will suffice. Most probably, **if** they had someone smart enough, who cared enough and who had access, they'd switch to thumbdrives, but... which MC is smart enough **and** cares enough? "I'm going to buy a new computer. How much? Two pistols. No."